# j2me development on ubuntu

Tags: linux, java-me

Where can I get a touchable emulator to develop j2me on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you use the WTK2.5? Then you can enable touch support for most of the standard emulator skins. Right now, I'm sitting on a Windows machine and can't lookup the exact path. In Windows you have to edit the file

c:\WTK2.5.2_01\wtklib\devices\DefaultColorPhone\DefaultColorPhone.properties

Change the line

touch_screen=false

to

touch_screen=true

and your DefaultColorPhone skin shows up with mouse (aka touch) support.

I'm pretty sure, that you find a similar file on your Linux box.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Visit Nokia's developer site and download S60 platform SDK. Releases after S60 5th edition supports touch screen (works on Windows and Ubuntu)

[Reference is here](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/ec866fab-4b76-49f6-b5a5-af0631419e9c/S60_All_in_One_SDKs.html)

Comment: Thanks,can you tell me how to make it work on Ubuntu?I downloaded N97 SDK,but it only has a setup.exe file,and I don't know how to use it on Ubuntu...

Comment: There are set of documents in Nokia's site explaining how to install for Ubuntu. Can't really recall right now where they are, but they exists :) I did it several times